# Setting direction to clockwise using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, diagram, chart

I am looking for a way to change the direction of the pie charts of a layer from counter-clockwise to clockwise in QGIS 3. I looked in the docs but I don´t seem to find a way to do this. Does anybody know what I need to do?

I create the pie charts like this:

```py
current_colors = {}  # maps the field names to QColor objects
diagram = QgsPieDiagram()
ds = QgsDiagramSettings()
ds.categoryColors = current_colors.values()
ds.categoryAttributes = current_colors.keys()
ds.categoryLabels = ds.categoryAttributes

dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
max_val = layer.maximumValue(layer.fields().indexFromName(pie_sum_col))
dr.setUpperValue(max_val)
dr.setLowerSize(QSizeF(2, 2))
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(40, 40))
dr.setClassificationField(pie_sum_col)
dr.setDiagram(diagram)
dr.setDiagramSettings(ds)
    
layer.setDiagramRenderer(dr)
dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
dls.setPlacement(1)
layer.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: What is the `current_colors` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify. It is a dictionary that maps the field names of the layer to some QColor objects (I also added a comment in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS Diagram settings way :

```py
ds = QgsDiagramSettings()
# counter-clockwise direction
ds.setDirection(QgsDiagramSettings.Counterclockwise)
# clockwise direction
ds.setDirection(QgsDiagramSettings.Clockwise)
```

---

Basic way :

Your current Python dictionnary is :

```py
current_colors = {
    '"field_one"': QColor("#FF0000"),
    '"field_two"': QColor("#00FF00"),
    '"field_three"': QColor("#0000FF"),
}
```

The result are diagrams in counter-clockwise order.
So, just reverse the order of `current_colors` :

```py
current_colors = {
    '"field_three"': QColor("#0000FF"),
    '"field_two"': QColor("#00FF00"),
    '"field_one"': QColor("#FF0000"),
}
```

or if you don't want to do this manually :

```py
current_colors = {k: current_colors[k] for k in reversed(current_colors)}
```

The result will be diagrams in clockwise order.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately this is not exactly what I intended. When you look in the GUI at the layer tree you will still have to inspect the different entries counter-clockwise since their order will also shift. If I however, click on the layer -> properties -> Diagrams -> Rendering and set the Direction to Clockwise it will do as intended. Is there not the possibility to trigger this via pyqgis?

Comment: @Christian: ok, I didn't know this option, so, see my edit.

Comment: Perfect, that works just fine! Thanks for the help.